# Directly grouping rows from pandas.DataFrame through matplotlib plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Dataframe saved as a `.csv` file that is similar to the one produced by the following code:

```
dates = [["2022-03-31", "A",100], ["2022-03-31", "B",100],  ["2022-03-31", "C", 250], ["2022-04-31", "A", 500], ["2022-04-31", "B", 100], ["2022-04-31", "C", 200], ["2022-05-31", "A",200], ["2022-05-31", "B", 300], ["2022-05-31", "C", 500]]

df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['Dates',"Payment Method", "Values"])

df.to_csv("example.csv",index=False)
```

What I am trying to do is to set each month of the year (in the "Dates" column) as a singular x axis tick using `matplotlib.pyplot` and create a line for each payment method ("Payment Method" column)  with its corresponding values ("Values" column) on the y axis for each month on the x axis. So for the payment method a

How would I go about directly grouping the months in the "Dates" row and plot 3 different lines (for payment methods "A", "B" and "C") with their corresponding values for each month using `pandas` and `matplotlib`?

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data. This is hard to copy'n'past. Did you try anything so far?

Comment: [How to fix x-axis showing two values with multi-line plot using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73659044/how-to-fix-x-axis-showing-two-values-with-multi-line-plot-using-matplotlib) may give you an idea on how to group the data and do a lines plot (axis month, lines A, B, C).

Comment: @mosc9575 I have added a code that reproduces the same DataFrame. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions. The first is using pandas only. Pandas makes it easy to plot data and the backend is matplotlib, too. The second solution uses matplotlib.

### Data handling

Before I start, I want to comment, that I don't use [`pd.groupby()`], because in this case [`df.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) is more useful and brings your DataFrame into a nice shape like this

```
dates = [["2022-03-31", "A",100], ["2022-03-31", "B",100],  ["2022-03-31", "C", 250], ["2022-04-31", "A", 500], ["2022-04-31", "B", 100], ["2022-04-31", "C", 200], ["2022-05-31", "A",200], ["2022-05-31", "B", 300], ["2022-05-31", "C", 500]]
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['Dates',"Payment Method", "Values"])
df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].str[:7]
df_pivot = df.pivot('Dates', 'Payment Method', 'Values')

>>> df_pivot
Payment Method    A    B    C
Dates                        
2022-03         100  100  250
2022-04         500  100  200
2022-05         200  300  500
```

which is easy to plot for both solutions.

As long you dates are of type `string`, you could `replace()` or slice the strings to remove the days.

In gerneral I suggest to parse dates to a datetime object using [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

but this gives you an error, because `"2022-04-31"` is not a valid date. Maybe this is something you should think about.

### Pandas plot

```
fig = df_pivot .plot.bar()
```

The `fig` variable is of type `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`. As you can see, pandas uses matplotlib and if you want to make changes to this figure, this is still possible afterwards. I think there is no need to use plain `matplotlib`.

[image: barplot after pivot]

I am not sure if your want a bar plot, but you can switch to [`df_pivot.plot.line()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html) or other [methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html?highlight=kind), too.

### Matplotlib

This solution is pretty much based on the [matplotlib barplot example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(len(df_pivot))
width = 0.2 # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

rects1 = ax.bar(x - width, df_pivot['A'], width, label='A')
rects2 = ax.bar(x, df_pivot['B'], width, label='B')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width, df_pivot['C'], width, label='C')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Value')
ax.set_title('Value by group and date')
ax.set_xticks(x, df.index)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: plain matplotlib example]

As you can see, this needs some more lines of code.

Comment: Hello, this is almost the result I was looking for. Is there a way to do this with matplotlib instead? If this requires modifying the structure of the pandas DataFrame object, could you please recommend that structure? Thanks.

Comment: Also, I am not sure why the question was closed, except for the reproducible example not being easy to copy and paste (which I edited). The only reason provided is that it needs to be more focused. It would be really appreciated if you could tell me what the main concepts this question touches on so I can edit the question.

Comment: @double_wizz I didn't close the question and I also didn't vote it down, but there are some issues with your question. 1. It is not clear which type of a plot do you want. The bar plot is a guess, but a line or scatter plot are also options. 2. You posted an image of your date. 3. You didn't show what you have tried. 
I think these are the main reasons.